# Google Maps API redraw bounds on geocode

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I am creating a google map that has a list of locations and then I want the user to be able to enter their(any) address into the map.  Once they enter their address, a new marker must show and the bounds of the map need to update to include the new location.

I've successfully been able to set the new location as a cookie and redraw the bounds of the map on load, however when I try and do this on the geocode input click, the new marker loads, but the bounds seem to only redraw around the new location.

How can I get the bounds to redraw on the input?

Dev site link: http://rosemontdev.com/google-maps-api/

Here is my code:

```
var locations = [
    ['Dripping Springs', 30.194826, -97.99839],
    ['Steiner Ranch', 30.381754, -97.884735],
    ['Central Austin', 30.30497, -97.744086],
    ['Pflugerville', 30.450049, -97.639163],
    ['North Austin', 30.41637, -97.704623],
];

var currentLocationMarker = "http://rosemontdev.com/google-maps-api/wp-content/themes/rm-theme/images/current.png";
var locationMarker = "http://rosemontdev.com/google-maps-api/wp-content/themes/rm-theme/images/pin.png";


function initMap() {

    window.map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
    });

    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
    var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();

    document.getElementById('submit').addEventListener('click', function() {
        geocodeAddress(geocoder, map);

    });



    for (i = 0; i < locations.length; i++) {
        marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: new google.maps.LatLng(locations[i][1], locations[i][2]),
            map: map,
            icon: locationMarker,
        });

        var circle = new google.maps.Circle({
            map: map,
            radius: 3000,
            fillColor: '#2B98B0',
            fillOpacity: 0.2,
            strokeOpacity: 0.25,
        });
        circle.bindTo('center', marker, 'position');

        bounds.extend(marker.position);

        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', (function (marker, i) {
            return function () {
                infoWindow.setContent(locations[i][0]);
                infoWindow.open(map, marker);
            }
        })(marker, i));

    } //closing for locations loop

    var locationValue = Cookies.get('rmLocationCookie-Place');
    var longValue = Cookies.get('rmLocationCookie-Long');
    var latValue = Cookies.get('rmLocationCookie-Lat');
    currentLocationNewMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: new google.maps.LatLng(longValue, latValue),
        map: map,
        icon: currentLocationMarker,
    });

    bounds.extend(currentLocationNewMarker.position);

    map.fitBounds(bounds);

} //closing initMap




function geocodeAddress(geocoder, resultsMap) {

    var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
    var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
    geocoder.geocode({'address': address}, function(results, status) {
        if (status === 'OK') {

            var currentLocationData = [];
            var bounds = new google.maps.LatLngBounds();
            var currentLocationName = 'Current Location';
            var currentLocationLong = results[0]['geometry']['bounds']['f']['b'];
            var currentLocationLat = results[0]['geometry']['bounds']['b']['b'];
            currentLocationData.push(currentLocationName, currentLocationLong, currentLocationLat);

            //Location Value Entered
            Cookies.set('rmLocationCookie-Place', address);
            //Geocoded Long
            Cookies.set('rmLocationCookie-Long', currentLocationLong);
            //Geocoded Lat
            Cookies.set('rmLocationCookie-Lat', currentLocationLat);

            var locationValue = Cookies.get('rmLocationCookie-Place');
            if(locationValue === undefined){
                console.log('no cookie set');
                $('#cookie-notice').html('Your location is not saved.');
            }
            else{
                $('#cookie-notice').html('Your location is saved as ' + locationValue +'');
            }

            updatedCurrentLocationMarker = new google.maps.Marker({
                position: new google.maps.LatLng(currentLocationLong, currentLocationLat),
                map: map,
                icon: currentLocationMarker,
            });

            bounds.extend(updatedCurrentLocationMarker.position);

            map.fitBounds(bounds);


        } else {
            alert('Geocode was not successful for the following reason: ' + status);
        }

    });
}
```

Comment: Do you want the bounds based on the geocoded result plus your data?

Comment: Yes, that is what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

Keep track of the original bounds before each geocode.

Then once the geocode completes pan to the marker and get the new map bounds the.

The idea is then to union the old and new bounds together using the. Union method then use the result as tour new map boundary.

```
originalbounds.union(newbounds)
```

Comment: Was able to get this working using a similar idea based on what you suggested above.  Thanks.

Comment: Great please mark my answer correct and up-vote my answer if it helped you.